# Android Studio New Drawer activity doesn't show any components but name of layout appears on Designer

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, navigation-drawer

I am new to android studio and am seriously facing most of problems due to errors without reason. I tried to create an empty Drawer activity but doesn't show any components but name of layout appears on Designer.

I'm getting rendering error and also Failed to initiate classes error even when I haven't change single word.

I tried some solutions mentioned on stack-overflow but none worked.

**Error**

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show 
Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, 
Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show 
Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample 
data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try 
to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard
```

Here is image of designer [image]

Comment: did u check whether the dependencies are added or not?

Comment: @Sabarinathan yes man everything is added well I'm really frustrated. 1st it happened with basic empty activity that none of components showed in designer and I had to waste a day and finally found that changing theme would fix it and now this.

Answer (score 0):

Well after searching google for about three to four days finally found a work around.

I changed SDK version from 28 to 26 and in build.gradle file replaced 28 by 26 and it worked. Finally.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.itnoa.asdf"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I hope this helps someone else :-)